# CoreAudio produces errors when playing AudioServicesPlayAlertSound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

I'm currently working on an application that is consistently listening. While it is recording, I sometimes play an alert sound and vibration using

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(...);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(...);
```

I notice that sometimes, as I put the app in the background while it's about to play or playing a sound/vibration, it throws the following error in the console log:

```
Error -10868
```

followed by

```
ERROR: [0x16e19f000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!pla' (enable 1, outf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
```

followed by

```
Error opening capture session. OSStatus error code: 561015905
```

I've tried looking these errors up but have had no luck with implementing a solution. I notice that when I resume the application, it is no longer detecting audio.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In general, iOS apps are not allowed to start playing audio from the background state.  An error from attempting to do so might kill the app's audio unit graph (including recording).

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion - I need to be a bit more testing around this. But thank you! If any other suggestions come up, I'd be so grateful to hear them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does ***configuring the audio session using a mixable category configuration*** help? Haven't tested but mentioning incase it may alter the observed behavior.